# I want to use multiple buttons for one timer with different actions

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to press the button and wait till the timer hits 0, so it will paste whatever is in the text box, but I want another button to paste from another textbox using the same timer.

Right now i only managed to solve it by having one timer for each button.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
        label1.Text = counter.ToString();
                     
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        this.label1.Text = counter.ToString();
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            SendKeys.SendWait(textBox2.ToString());
            counter = 5;
            label1.Text = "5";
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Timers, I'd write a separate sub that uses async/await.  Then you can just call it from the buttons with different parameters:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendText(button1, label1, textBox1.Text, 5);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendText(button2, label2, textBox2.Text, 3);
}

private async void SendText(Button btn, Label lbl, string txt, int seconds)
{
    btn.Enabled = false;
    int counter = seconds;
    while (counter > 0)
    {
        lbl.Text = counter.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        counter--;
    }
    lbl.Text = counter.ToString();
    SendKeys.SendWait(txt);
    btn.Enabled = true;
}
```